# Crystal Report "The system cannot find the path specified" with WebAPI and Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, crystal-reports, asp.net-web-api

I am getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error when exporting from WebAPI Restful web service.  My development environments are:

- Windows 7 SP1 x64 Bit
- Visual Studio 2013 Community
- Crystal Report Support Pack 14 (v.13.0.14.1720)
- DotNet 4.5.1 oracle instant client 11.2 (both x86 and x64)
- Oracle 11g R2

I have seen a number of posts, suggesting "The system cannot find the path specified" is related to the database connections not being set properly.  To debug, I have done the following things to eliminate such possibility:

1. Remove all sub-report
2. Display only a single table with a single columns
3. Run the report as an executable program (And it works)

Since I was able to export the report in a exe program, I was thinking maybe crystal report is not compatible with  WebAPI.  To check, I've created a report connecting to MS SQL Server, and it works.

Given I have proved there is no database connections error, and crystal report can be generated from WebAPI (At least for MSSQL), I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out what's the problem.

This is the source code of my attempts so far
https://bitbucket.org/yilik01/crystalreporttest.git

And this is the error exception

```
{
  "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage" : "The system cannot find the path specified.\r",
  "ExceptionType" : "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException",
  "StackTrace" : " 
  at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)\r\n 
  at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)\r\n 
  at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)\r\n 
  at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)\r\n 
  at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)\r\n 
  at reportManager.ReportManager.generateOracleReport() in c:\\Temp\\WebApplication1\\reportManager\\ReportManager.cs:line 31\r\n 
  at WebAPI.Controllers.DefaultController.getOracleReport() in c:\\Temp\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\Controllers\\DefaultController.cs:line 16\r\n 
  at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n 
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n 
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n 
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n 
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n 
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using crystal report classes which only work when running within windows executables which utilise COM. By default web servers (like IIS) don't have access into COM objects and nor should they as it is a security issue.

luckily crystal has a set of libraries which you can use within a web server. The ones we directly reference in the web project are CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, CrystalDecisions.ReportSource and CrystalDecisions.Shared

these are available once you install the 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework' redist